# PHP + JAVASCRIPT SAVE DATA

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is the controller:

```
 public function routeupdateAction() {
    $iRoute = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'id', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $sPath = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'path', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $sModule = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'module', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $sController = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'controller', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $sAction = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'action', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $iAccessRole = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'accessRole', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );
    $iRoleCompareOperator = IV_Http_Base::getParameter( 'roleCompareOperator', IV_Http_Base::HTTP_POST );

    $oRoute = Default_Model_RouteEntity::getInstanceById( $iRoute );
    if( is_object( $oRoute ) && $oRoute instanceof Default_Model_RouteEntity ) {
        $oRoute->setPath( $sPath );
        $oRoute->setModule( $sModule );
        $oRoute->setController( $sController );
        $oRoute->setAction( $sAction );
        $oRoute->setAccessRole($iAccessRole);
        $oRoute->setRoleCompareOperator($iRoleCompareOperator);
        $oRoute->save();

        $aReturn = array( 'valid' => 'true' );
    } else  {
        $aReturn = array( 'valid' => 'false' );
    }
        echo json_encode( $aReturn );
    }
}
```

The route.js file

```
var ROUTE = new function () {
    var oGlobal = this;
    this.sSaveUrl = '';

    this.setSaveUrl = function (_sUrl) {
        this.sSaveUrl = _sUrl;
    }

    this.setEventSubmit = function () {
        $('[id^="route_update"]').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var oData = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serializeArray();
                console.log(oData);

                oReq = $.post(oGlobal.sSaveUrl, oData, function (data) {
                    if (data['valid'] != "true") {
                        //console.log('error');
                        //Fade in
                        $('#comment').html('Insert Success').fadeIn(1000);
                        //Fade out
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000);
                        }, 1500);
                        //fade in
                        $('#comment')
                    } else {
                        // console.log('success');
                        //Fade in
                        $('#comment').html('Insert Success').fadeIn(1000);
                        //Fade out
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000);
                        }, 1500);
                        //fade in
                        $('#comment')
                    }
                    return false;
                }, 'json');

                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    this.init = function () {
        this.setEventSubmit();
    }
}
```

and the html markup

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <form class="well form-inline">
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="13%">Path</th>
        <th width="13%">Module</th>
        <th width="13%">Controller</th>
        <th width="13%">Action</th>
        <th width="13%">Access Role</th>
        <th width="13%">Compare Operator</th>
        <th width="9%">Submit</th>
    </tr>
    <?
    $aRoutes = $this->getValue('aRoutes');
    if( count($aRoutes) == 0 ) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">No routes found!</td>
        </tr>
    <?
    } else {
        /**
         * @var Default_Model_RouteEntity $oRoute
         */
        foreach ( $aRoutes as $oRoute) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" name="path" value="<?= $oRoute->getPath(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $oRoute->getModule(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $oRoute->getController(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $oRoute->getAction(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" class="form-actions" value="<?= $oRoute->getAccessRole(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="13%">
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $oRoute->getRoleCompareOperator(); ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td width="9%">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $oRoute->getId(); ?>" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="route_update">Edit</button>
                    <div id="comment"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?
        }
    } ?>
</table>
      </form>
</form>
<? $this->addJs('admin/cms/route'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ROUTE.setSaveUrl('<?=IV_Url_Base::url( 'admin_cms_routeupdate' ); ?>');
        ROUTE.init();
    });
</script>
```

My request is, as you can see the basic features are ready...Now what I need to implement is to save the data when i change a row.

This should be needed in js without refreshing the page lots of times and if the data are saved correctly you have a fade displaying the right saving..

How do I save the data when a row is changed?

Comment: Ok so I see you're also using jQuery. The code needed is pretty much more than a snippet, also, where do you want to save it? in a database? a text file? a binary file with your own format?

Comment: Need to save that to the db...

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the "form" tags.
2. Use jQuery to set onclick events on the buttons.
3. Use `parent('tr')` ([parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)) to retrieve row element.
4. Using the row element use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through `td` tags and save the data to some array: `$('td', $row).each(function () { /* parse td element */ });`
5. Send array to PHP script using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
6. Save the data in PHP script and display result to AJAX using [status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (200 - OK, 4** - ERROR)
7. If everything is working, use jQuery to do the animations you want.